# Replace whole line with sub-string in a text file - Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, text, io

New to ruby here!

How to replace the whole line in a text file which contains a specific string using ruby?

Example: I want to remove and add the whole line contains "**DB_URL**" and add something like "**DB_CON=jdbc:mysql:replication://master,slave1,slave2,slave3/test**"

`DB_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:TEST
 DB_USERNAME=USER
 DB_PASSWORD=PASSWORD`

Comment: Just to be sure, do you want to replace a line or the sentence ? (You could have several sentences per line)

Comment: Give an example and describe what you have tried so far.

Comment: I made changes in my code, please check it and let me know if old one is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt :

**file.txt**

```
First line
Second line
foo
bar
baz foo
Last line
```

**test.rb**

```
f = File.open("file.txt", "r")

a = f.map do |l|
  (l.include? 'foo') ? "replacing string\n" : l # Please note the double quotes
end 

p a.join('')
```

**Output**

```
$ ruby test.rb 
"First line\nSecond line\nreplacing string\nbar\nreplacing string\nLast line"
```

I commented `# Please note the double quotes` because single quotes will escape the `\n` (that will become `\\n`). Also, you might want to think about the last line of your file since it will add `\n` at the end of the last line when there will not have one at the end of your original file. If you don't want that you could make something like :

```
f = File.open("file.txt", "r")

a = f.map do |l|
  (l.include? 'foo') ? "replacing string\n" : l
end 

a[-1] = a[-1][0..-2] if a[-1] == "replacing string\n"

p a.join('')
```

Comment: Instead of throwing code over a wall, it is often a good idea to explain what the code does and how it helps solve the problem. This is often much more valuable than the actual code as it helps people to understand and solve similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution.

```
file_data = ""
word = 'Word you want to match in line'
replacement = 'line you want to set in replacement'

IO.foreach('pat/to/file.txt') do |line|
  file_data += line.gsub(/^.*#{Regexp.quote(word)}.*$/, replacement)
end

puts file_data

File.open('pat/to/samefile.txt', 'w') do |line|
  line.write file_data
end
```